# Backup many small files

Tags: lvm

We have many small files on EXT3/LVM. Many-many million.

We cannot backup them using file backup, it would take too much time.

We currently have TSM image backup that uses LVM snapshot.

If a backup runs for ex.: 250 GByte data, +250 GByte needed, so sum 500 GByte, since of the LVM snapshot.

**Question:** How can we make backup without additional space? Using tar/pipe/ssh is bad, since that one would use file backup, too slow..

**UPDATE**: Moving the small files to DB is not a solution (but it would be logical.. but we cannot do it)

**UPDATE#2:** Files could change, so backup couldn't be a slow one, avoiding an inconsistent state. The files are on one filesystem..

Comment: We use ZFS and snapshots which are instant. Then we use `zfs send` and `zfs receive` to transfer the data to the backup server. Snapshots operate on a block level and therefore are unaffected by the number of files. I don't know LVM and it's capabilities, though. Maybe ZFS is an option, maybe LVM can do something similar.

Comment: you could always use dd to copy the underlying byte image stream, but I'm not sure that would perform better.

Comment: hmm, do you think it could produce a consistent backup while we are talking about several hundred GBytes that could change while copying?

Comment: @LoukiosValentine79 indeed not. Hence you'd need to first make an LVM snapshot and *then* copy it. Cf. http://theshed.hezmatt.org/lvmsync/  https://serverfault.com/questions/41020/is-this-how-lvm-snapshots-work